# F# working with while loop

Tags: f#

I have a datareader and i want to return collection of rows from it, after reading books for like a day i am not able to find out best way to do it in f#. I can do it normal C# way in F# but that is not why i am using f#

Here is what i am trying to achieve

```
let values =
    while reader.Read() do
        yield reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt64(1)
```

Above is how i am trying to do

- all values get collected into values, which could be dictinary or tuples or any collection
- yield can't be used in while loop but that is what i am trying to do

What could be the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

F# also provides list comprehension for arrays and sequences.

```
let records_as_list = 
    [
        while reader.Read() 
            do yield (reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt64(1)) 
    ]

let records_as_array = 
    [|
        while reader.Read() 
            do yield (reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt64(1)) 
    |]

let records_as_sequence = 
    seq {
        while reader.Read() 
            do yield (reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt64(1)) 
    }
```

F# has a convenient dictionary function built in called `dict`

```
let records_as_IDictionary = dict records_as_sequence
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use sequence expressions to implement enumerators:

```
let records = seq { while reader.NextResult() do yield (reader.GetString(0), reader.GetInt64(1)) }
```

If you need more than two fields, you can yield maps of column index (or name) -> field values (untested code):

```
let dbSchema = reader.GetSchemaTable()

let makeMap (rdr : IDataReader) (schema : DataTable) =
    schema.Columns |> Seq.cast<DataColumn> |> Seq.map (fun col -> (col.ColumnName, rdr.[col.ColumnName])) |> Map.ofSeq

let records = seq { while reader.NextResult() do yield (makeMap reader dbSchema) }
```

Comment: Problem with seq is that it does lazy loading so when you want to read it in this case reader would be closed

Comment: Easily fixed by appending |> Seq.toList to the last row to materialise the collection.

Answer (score 3):

For this kind of task, I'd like to first transfer the input into a sequence of strings.

.Net 4.0 provides ReadLines, the type of its return value is `seq<string>`:

```
   open System.IO
   let readLinesSeq = File.ReadLines
```

In lower versions of .Net, one needs to implement this function:

```
   let readLines filePath = seq {
    use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
    while not sr.EndOfStream do
     yield sr.ReadLine ()
   }
```

Comment: Yes, the basic idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I might approach this problem more generically by adding an extension property to `IDataReader` that turns any datareader into a `seq<IDataRecord>`...

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module DataReaderEx =
    open System.Data

    type IDataReader with
        member this.toSeq =
            seq { while this.Read() do yield this :> IDataRecord }
```

This would allow you to use ordinary functions from the `Seq` module on any datareader:

```
reader.toSeq
|> Seq.map (fun row -> row.GetString(0), row.GetInt64(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well we are not talking about files here, however, in earlier .NET versions you can do (with small files):

```
reader.ReadToEnd().Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())
```

Where `reader` is a TextReader.

Comment: If the file is big, reading all the content and splitting should be avoided.

Comment: In this question, `reader` is actually an IDataReader, not a TextReader